# how to get records who is reaching todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get records who are about reach todays date with in 2 days ProjectEnddt. i want to show Projects who are going to end with in 2 days. want to show  2 days before.

Comment: So what's the problem with the query you already have?

Comment: im not getting any records@Mureinik

Comment: im just inserting in string . can we retrieve if we insert in string field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT ProjectEndDt
       , ProjectRenewalDt 
       , ProjectUpgradeDt
FROM   tbl_project
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 2, ProjectEndDt)) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProjectEndDt
   ,ProjectRenewalDt 
   ,ProjectUpgradeDt
FROM tbl_project
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE,[ProjectEndDt]) < DATEADD(DAY, 3,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProjectEndDt
       ,ProjectRenewalDt 
       ,ProjectUpgradeDt
FROM tbl_project       
WHERE  CAST(ProjectEndDt AS DATE) < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```